# get value from a django form using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I was trying for a long time to figure out how to get the value from a django.form using javascript, however I didn't get any straight answer to it.
here is my project:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import TextForm
from .Functions import GetData


def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            print("is valid")
            text = form.cleaned_data['date']
            x = GetData(text.day, text.month, text.year)
            x.getInfo()
            context = {
                'text': text,
                'form': form,
            }
            return render(request, 'index.html', context)

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = TextForm()
        print("not valid")

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class TextForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(), label="inputDate")
```

let's say the html file is very basic, like this:

```
<form action=" " method="post" id="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}                 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

SO the main thing, that I need, is to get the date value from the form

Comment: Have you tried right clicking and inspect element on the date and time ? You can try using Jquery by doing something like this: $( "inputDate" ).labels().addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )

Comment: so I can somehow add a class, or an Id to the label, right ?

Comment: Yes, Use jquery labels() you can add class, id or simply modify values